# Calculate cor() in a data.frame with non numerical data

Tags: r, correlation

I want to calculate a correlation matrix for a 10 column `data.frame` that contains 2 factor columns. If I run `cor(data.frame)` I get the non numerical error. Is there any other way to run it, besides creating a new data frame with just the numerical columns?

Comment: `cor(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your data frame looks like. But, I get the impression that you try to run correlation for all columns you got. I leave the following for you.

```
#sample data
subject <- 1:100
area <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), each = 20)
a <- runif(100, 0, 50)
b <- runif(100, 20, 60)
c <- runif(100, 10, 70)

foo <- data.frame(subject, area, a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cor(foo[,c(3:5)], use = "everything") #select columns with numbers

#          a           b           c
#a 1.0000000  0.16797099  0.11609168
#b 0.1679710  1.00000000 -0.01162148
#c 0.1160917 -0.01162148  1.00000000
```

Comment: If `subject` is also factor.  `cor(foo[sapply(foo, is.numeric)])` would also work. +1

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the follow-up. That will help the OP.